# splicer c# an invalid media type was specified

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, splicer

I would like to join two or more videos in c# Application.So I'm using Splicer library.But I am using following but i throws exception "An invalid media type was specified".How to solve this I have tried a lot to solve it.

```
using (ITimeline timeLine = new DefaultTimeline())
            {
                IGroup group = timeLine.AddVideoGroup(32, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
                var c1=group.AddTrack().AddVideo("m1.mp4");
                var c2 = group.AddTrack().AddVideo("m2.mp4",c1.Duration);
                using (AviFileRenderer render = new AviFileRenderer(timeLine, "m.avi"))
                {
                    render.Render();
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Have Performed!!!");
```

Answer (score 0):

By default DirectShow does not support .mp4 files. You need to install a codec pack for it to support;

Install the following codecpack and try again;

http://www.cccp-project.net/